# Installing .net site locally results in "This page can't be displayed"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I've received some files for a site I'd like to update and am trying to get it running in IIS locally. IIS is working - if I go to http://localhost I get the index.htm file - but if I go to http://localhost/aspxsite/ (their files) I get "This page can't be displayed".

I'm very unfamiliar with this stuff - any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm running IIS 7.5.7600.16385 on Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open IIS Manager.

2. In the Connections pane, right-click the Sites node in the tree, and then click Add Web Site.

3.In the Physical path box, type the physical path of the Web site's folder, or click the browse button (...) to navigate the file system to find the folder.

4. Go to  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt and add this line:

127.0.0.1                 aspxSiteName

5. Type in browser http://aspxSiteName